# No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, ngrok

I'm working on the marketplace application. When payout to a connect account from the platform, I want to update account's balance information and add receipt model on my application. But `No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload` error occurs and I can't get `payout.paid` event.

*stripe.rb*

```
StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  # The case transfer created
  events.subscribe(
    'payout.paid',
    Events::PayoutPaid.new
  )
end
```

*apps/services/events/payout_paid.rb*

```
class Events::PayoutPaid
  def call(event)
    source = event.data.object

    # Fetch balence information
    account = source.destination
    balance = Stripe::Balance.retrieve(
        {stripe_account: account}
      )

    @user = User.find_by({
      stripe_account_id: account
    })
    @user.balance = balance["available"][0]["amount"]
    @user.save

    # create receipt
    @receipt = Receipt.new
    @receipt.user = @user
    @receipt.amount = source.amount
    @receipt.save
  end
end
```

Although other stripe webhook would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and the solution was to:

1. log into Stripe
2. go to the page for the webhook that was failing
3. get the Signing secret from the middle of that page
4. and set an env VAR called STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET with the Signing secret as its value.

This is mentioned in the Stripe docs, [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures).

Answer (score 2):

That is because you havent loaded the signing secrets to StripeEvent

Lest say you create 2 webhooks on the Stripe dashboard, one subscribed to invoices events, the other to customer events. You first need to copy each of the Signing secret (click on reveal) and then store them in the `config/credentials.yml.enc` file

First, run the command `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` (using the editor of your choosing). Then, add the following values:

```
    stripe:
      development:
        secret_key: MY_SECRET_KEY
        publishable_key: MY_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        signing_secret_customer_endpoint: MY_SIGNING_SECRET_CUSTOMERS
        signing_secrets_invoice_endpoint: MY_SIGNING_SECRET_INVOICES
```

Save the file. Now edit the initializer for stripeEvent. In my case, it was `config/initializers/stripe.rb` and add:

```
StripeEvent.signing_secrets = [
  Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][Rails.env.to_sym][:signing_secret_customer_endpoint],
  Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][Rails.env.to_sym][:signing_secrets_invoice_endpoint]]
```

Now the signing secrets are loaded and the webhooks should work